# NodeMCU Build in Docker results in "exec format error"

Tags: docker, nodemcu

I'm trying the NodeMCU Docker build in Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS for the first time.
I have read the tagged articles here for Docker and NodeMCU, but don't see this particular error.

"docker run hello-world"  has no problems.

I have tried the NodeMCU build command in both forms:

```
$ docker run --rm -ti -v `pwd`:/opt/nodemcu-firmware marcelstoer/nodemcu-build
```

and the explicit path variation:

```
$ docker run --rm -it -v /home/tim/nodemcu-firmware:/opt/nodemcu-firmware marcelstoer/nodemcu-build
```

In both cases, I get this error:

```
standard_init_linux.go:187: exec user process caused "exec format error"
```

I have searched on this error, and [most solutions are related](https://www.lewuathe.com/exec-format-error-in-docker-container.html) to a missing shebang.

However, I'm not sure what script would need the shebang, or why it would be not working in my case but correct for others.
Has anyone else run across this error?

Comment: As for "what script would need the shebang": the Dockerfile at https://github.com/marcelstoer/docker-nodemcu-build/blob/master/Dockerfile#L20 runs https://github.com/marcelstoer/docker-nodemcu-build/blob/master/cmd.sh and it has a shebang.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking without deep technical details, this error means that the kernel can not recognize the format of the executable file, thus, it can not run this file. In your case this error is about the executable file which is started when the container is launched. According to the `Cmd` entry in the output of `docker inspect marcelstoer/nodemcu-build`, it is a file `/bin/sh`, which is an ELF executable.

When Linux can not execute ELF binary and returns such an error (about the file format), it usually is related to the system architecture. More specifically, the image `marcelstoer/nodemcu-build` contains `ELF64` executables (i.e. for `amd64` architecture), and your system does not support it (is it `i386` or even some flavor of `arm`?). Running `docker run hello-world`, however, works fine for you, because `hello-world` image exists for all architectures supported by Docker.

According to the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/marcelstoer/docker-nodemcu-build/blob/master/Dockerfile#L1) of `marcelstoer/nodemcu-build` image, it is built from `ubuntu`, which exists for different architectures, thus, you may try building the `marcelstoer/nodemcu-build` image on your system rather than pulling it from the dockerhub.

P.S.: regarding the solution you have linked to your question. This is not about your case (ELF binary), rather it is about a script. In case of script, the executable format is recognized by the shebang (`#!`) at the very beginning of the file, thus, the script **must** start with `#!`, not with the newline. That's why the author got the same error: the kernel could not detect that this is a script and failed to start it. Different (but similar) reasons, same error.

Comment: I had docker already installed and set up on a 32-bit Ubuntu system.  As you noted, nodemcu-build requires 64.  AFAIK there is no clean way to migrate an existing 32 bit Ubuntu to 64 bit.

Comment: If `nodemcu` requires 64-bit to build, using docker will not help to perform a build on the 32-bit system, as any process in the docker container still uses the host kernel and hardware.